# Add all files from last commit to staging area?

Tags: git

I created a big project on my raspberry pi, i initialized a new git repository on the root directory. I have files on various locations e.g. `/etc/myscripts/script1.sh`, `/var/www/mywebsite`, `/usr/bin/somescript.sh`.

I added these files to the staging area and made a first commit. How can i always add the files which i added in the last commit to the staging area with one command? I know i could execute `git add *` but this would also add files which are not from my project.

My idea is to write a bash script which works like this:

```
#/bin/bash
git add /var/www/mywebsite
git add /etc/myscripts/script1.sh
git add /usr/bin/somescript.sh
```

But then i always have to update the script if new files are being added to the project.. is there a better way, maybe something like `git add allFromLast`?

Answer (score 1):

Two Way in my point of view :

Reverse your issue.

Add all the file you don't want to add to stage in .gitignore.

then you just have to execute command :

```
git add *
```

OR

Create a bash (sh or perl) to add it programmatically based on the command which list the file from the last commit :

```
git show --pretty="format:" --name-only HEAD
```